# Software that guides through the process of creative thinking

Tags: thinking-tool

I wonder if there is software that guides through creative thinking processes*. The wished tool

- goes **beyond** mind-mapping / brain storming,
- **guides** through different creative thinking techniques in wizard modes,
- helps to **rapidly** jot down results and organize them later,
- is suitable both for individuals as well as for team meetings and
- is available as windows desktop or web app.

---

*described in the literature:

- [Edward De Bono's Thinking Course](http://books.google.de/books?id=2bbEZUMJsy4C&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [Gamestorming: A Playbook for Innovators, Rulebreakers, and Changemakers](http://books.google.de/books?id=_-xnEDNPxwYC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

[xmind](http://www.xmind.net/) should fit your needs.

- Windows Application
- Exports to Excel/Powerpoint (in paid version)
- Very simple, very efficient to use with a group in a room (after a easy, quick learning curve)
- Can be used to task and track tasking (not as robust as say outlook or a true work tracking application

[image]

You can drill down into any of the non-core items (in this picture EID) and make them the center of the plan to help focus work on one item.  Files can be directly attached to any of the subordinate items and markers (like check marks, questions marks (right side of screen shot) can be added to each item)

This is just one chart type, the program provides fishbone, mindmapping, matrix and brainstorming features, provides tasking and dates complete with Gantt views.  Compatible with office and PDF.

The tool has a free to use version and a paid version, the full paid version is still only 99 USD, worth trying since it costs nothing play.

Comment: This is an excellent program, but now you have to pay for the full version.